# Applied output was not able to destroy failed with a saved plan is stale

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm creating one compute instance through a terraform plan via OCI. The stages are to develop an independent workspace, validate the current configuration (provider.tf and compute.tf, which stays in the same directory.), and apply the plan. The instance was created and working, but nothing happened when I tried to destroy it, even after state pull and refresh.

I have two questions:

1. When I'm trying to destroy `terraform apply -destroy tfplan`, the currently created machine with tfplan, I get the message "Saved plan is stale.". How to fix that?
2. Can I run multiple plans in one directory and destroy them by creating an id/name?

Steps to reproduce the issue:

```
terraform init -input=false
terraform workspace select test || terraform workspace new test
terraform validate
terraform plan \
-var compute_shape="VM.Standard.E4.Flex" \
-var compute_cpus="1" \
-var compute_memory_in_gbs="1" \
-var compute_name="test" \
-var compute_image_id="ocid1.image....." \
-var compartment_id="ocid1.compartment....."" \
-var vnic_subnet_id="ocid1.subnet.oc1.iad....."" \
-var vnic_assign_public_ip="true" -no-color -out=tfplan -input=false -detailed-exitcode -lock=true
terraform apply tfplan
terraform state pull
terraform apply -destroy tfplan
```

Failed output after destroy command:

```
╷
│ Error: Saved plan is stale
│
│ The given plan file can no longer be applied because the state was changed by another operation after the plan was created.
╵
```

Comment: What is the reason for repetaedly executing `terraform state pull`?

Comment: The wrong alligment should be before destroying command.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that can delete the created instance, and the steps are just to repeat the whole plan but with the option `-destroy`.
So the resolution can be like that:

```
terraform plan -destroy \
-var compute_shape="VM.Standard.E4.Flex" \
-var compute_cpus="1" \
-var compute_memory_in_gbs="1" \
-var compute_name="test" \
-var compute_image_id="ocid1.image....." \
-var compartment_id="ocid1.compartment....."" \
-var vnic_subnet_id="ocid1.subnet.oc1.iad....."" \
-var vnic_assign_public_ip="true" -no-color -out=tfplan
terraform apply tfplan
```